# How to get different server MapPath

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, server, devexpress

i have 2 server one for save document file and second for my code

i wanna open document file first server to my second server

right now i am using richeditor and my code is:

```
@{string url = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Upload/WebDavServer/WebDavDocument/") + "tes.docx"; }
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var str = @url;
            var FilePath = str.replace(/\//g, '\\');
            $("#divRichEdit").load("/History/RichEditPartialview", { filePath: FilePath });
               });
    </script>
```

Comment: You will get path of server on which your code is running. There is no way to get document from other server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Imad you will not be able to use Server.Mappath to reference a different server than the one executing the call. However, as a possible workaround you can create a shared location on the other server that exposes the documents to your site and use that URL in your method.

You would then reference the URL similar to \ServerName\ShareLocation\Documents\TheDocIWant.pdf

Comment: Can you update your question with the relevant code where you try this?